# Как вытащить последнее слово?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```php
'<a href="#" class="point-camera point-camera-'.$style.'"><span class="img-point-camera"><img src="'.$img.'" alt="#"></span><span class="temp_city"><img src="'.$temp.'"><p>22°C</p></span><br>'.$post_name.'</a>'
```

Нужно вытащить последнее слово `$post_name`

Пытаюсь следующем образом:

```
...
$(this).last().text();
```

Выводит:
22°CTEXT

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Так как нужна последний текстовый узел, можно воспользоваться [методом contents](https://api.jquery.com/contents/) для получения всех вложенных узлов и взять последний:

```js
var node = $('a').contents().last();
console.log(node.text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="point-camera point-camera"><span class="img-point-camera"><img src="" alt="#"></span><span class="temp_city"><img src=""><p>22°C</p></span><br>Текст который нужно найти</a>
```